# Sonarqube web browser is missing in Eclipse sonar plugin 3.5

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

"Sonarqube web browser" option is missing in sonar plugin 3.5 which is installed in eclipse Neon. And the option is available in sonar plugin 3.4 but the analysis is not successful through eclipse Neon.

How to get the option ? Can anyone please help on this.

[image]

Regards,
Sangeetha K

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube Eclipse plugin has been deprecated and therefore is no more supported. As a consequence, chances are that you will never get an answer to your question.

Instead, I advise you to use [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Fabrice for your answer - Sangeetha K